# jstl bug while comparing strings UTF-8.(Spring Security - principal.username)

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, spring-security, jstl

my jsp page has:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
```

...

```
<c:set var="currentUser">
  <sec:authentication property = "principal.username"/>
</c:set>

<c:if test = "${currentUser eq user.login}" >
```

...
when i compare English words evaluation returns **true**, but when it comes to Russian language, etc - **false**.

At start i thought that this can be trouble with jsp encoding but when i run something like that

```
<c:if test = "${'Андрей' eq 'Андрей'}" >
```

it comes **true**
 even

```
<c:if test = "${currentUser eq 'Андрей'}" > turns `false`
```

At the end i want to add that browser displays values **${currentUser}** and **${user.login}** as the same

```
${currentUser}<br>
${user.login}
```

comes

```
Андрей
Андрей
```

Thanks in advance for your reply!

Comment: good catch, since you have gone this far, you could debug in corelib source http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/taglibs/standard/1.1.2/org/apache/taglibs/standard/lang/support/ExpressionEvaluatorManager.java#63

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this test page. It works for me.

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
<%
   pageContext.setAttribute( "currentUser", "Андрей");
%>
Test page.
<c:if test = "${currentUser eq 'Андрей'}" >
     Yes, they are equal.
</c:if> 
<c:if test = "${currentUser eq currentUser}" >
     Yes, they are equal. currentUesr is ${currentUser}
</c:if>
```

Output:
Test page.  Yes, they are equal.   Yes, they are equal. currentUesr is Андрей

Comment: Yes, sorry. your example works as it should do) i have lost some additional info needed to mention:
`<c:set var="currentUser">
  <sec:authentication property = "principal.username"/>
</c:set>` after those lines my evaluation turns false. seems so

Comment: Are you saying  that the problem lies outside of JSTL?

Comment: yes. the problem was in Spring Security. thanks for your reply. answer is <sec:authentication property="principal.username" htmlEscape="false" />. And as it turned out its a dublicate question)